# how to add comma repeatedly in string after every third element

Tags: ios, swift

i was trying to add comma to the string after every third character.

my code looks like this

```
var str = "12345678912345"

for (index,item) in str.enumerated() {
    if index % 3 == 0 {
        str.insert(",", at: str.index(of: item)!)
    }
}
print(str)
```

i expect the output "123,456,789,123,45" but the actual output is ",123,,456,78912345".

i can't work with Int or Double and use NumberFormatter because input could be more than Int or Double max values.

Comment: Try this solution, Someone might be knowing a better way, but this will also work..         let str = "12345678912345"
        var newStr = ""
        for (index,item) in str.enumerated() {
            if index % 3 == 0 {
                if newStr == "" {
                    newStr = item.description
                } else {
                    newStr = newStr + "," + item.description
                }
            } else {
                newStr = newStr + item.description
            }
        }
        print(newStr)

Comment: This is a pretty naive solution, but you can easily modify your existing code like this ```var offsets = [Int]()
var str = "12345678912345"

for (index,item) in str.enumerated() {
    if (index + 1) % 3 == 0 {
        offsets.append(index + 1)
    }
}
var commasAdded = 0
for offset in offsets{
    
    if offset + commasAdded < str.count{
        str.insert(",", at: String.Index(encodedOffset: offset + commasAdded))
    }
    commasAdded += 1
}

print(str)```

sorry for formatting, but I can't submit as an answer because the question was closed